# Android Emulator having very low onscreen quality

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

The android emulator on my system seems to be showing unclear texts and icons on emulator device, but if i take a screenshot from the emulator it seems to be clear and looks real.

Image below shows the emulator view and screenshot view.

[image: View on the emulator vs Screenshot from the emulator]

Here is the configuration file from ***.android/avd/config.ini***

```
AvdId=Pixel_XL_API_28
PlayStore.enabled=false
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=Pixel XL API 28
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
disk.dataPartition.size=800M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile=
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot=no
fastboot.forceColdBoot=yes
fastboot.forceFastBoot=no
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.arc=false
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=virtualscene
hw.camera.front=emulated
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.cpu.ncore=2
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:984dbf66b1aaafcdb7e89573ffb74b46
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=pixel_xl
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto
hw.initialOrientation=Portrait
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=560
hw.lcd.height=1280
hw.lcd.width=768
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=1536
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86/
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
sdcard.size=512M
showDeviceFrame=yes
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=pixel_2_xl
skin.path=/home/dev284/Android/Sdk/skins/pixel_2_xl
tag.display=Google APIs
tag.id=google_apis
vm.heapSize=384
```

Comment: same problem on MacBook 2022. Did you find how to fix it?